# VSTO Word 2010 Ribbon for multiple documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I'm looking for a way to create **new instances** of my ribbon class **for each new word document**.

I did play around with a button and a label and to my suprise, every word instance shows up the same data!
I want to show some data from the documents.

**Is it possible to tell the addin to construct a new ribbon class for every document ?**

Comment: after a lot of research, I know now, that there is one ribbon instance across all word instances and I have to do all button/label checkings again after each document-activation. so Sarvesh Mishra was right!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start different application of Word 2010 for each of your doc.

Or

Subscribe to Document Activate event and update ribbon when document is activated.

Office 2013 and behaves differntly than previous versions in terms of Ribbon and document management.

Comment: I am starting different applications (instances) of word

Comment: Then where you are getting the problem? Manipulate the Ribbon as you want using Code

Comment: In my second instance of my AddIn I am setting values to  Labels and Textboxes. After switching back to the first instance, those values will show up there as well.